# TypeError: Expected tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_spec.TensorSpec, found numpy.ndarray

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am getting the following error when i would like to migrate from TFF 0.12.0 to TFF 0.18.0,
Knowing that I have an image dataset, Here is my sample_batch

```
images, labels = next(img_gen.flow_from_directory(path0,target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=2))
sample_batch = (images,labels)
...

def model_fn():

  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=sample_batch,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

So how can I modifiy my sample_batch to be correct with this version ? please Help !! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version [`0.13.0`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.13.0) the `sample_batch` parameter was deprecated. The `input_spec` parameter must be a [`tff.Type`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/Type) or [`tf.TensorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorSpec) as per [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model#args).

To build a structure of `tf.TensorSpec` from a `numpy.ndarray`:

```py
def tensor_spec_from_ndarray(a):
  return tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.dtypes.as_dtype(a.dtype),
                       shape=a.shape)

sample_batch = (images,labels)  # assumes images and labels are np.ndarray
input_spec = tf.nest.map_structure(
  tensor_spec_from_ndarray, sample_batch)
```